# ValueError: Layer 'dense' expected 2 variables, but received 0 variables during loading. Expected: ['dense/kernel:0', 'dense/bias:0']

Tags: generator, pickle, layer, valueerror, h5py

I wanted to convert my pickle file to .h5 file and this was saved from a generator model. But it shows error.

code:

```
import pickle
import h5py

def convert_pickle_to_h5(pickle_file, h5_file):
\#Load data from pickle file
with open('/content/generator_model.pkl', 'rb') as f:
data = pickle.load(f) # error line
```

Can anyone please solve this problem or provide me code to convert pickle file to .h5py file?
Thanks in advance.